# For loop with if and elseif statements

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a simple problem, I'm trying to replace values in a 1x60000 array.

Here's my code, where `Z` is the 1x60000 array:

```
for i = 1:length(Z)
    if Z(i) == 140
       Z(i) = 1;
    elseif Z(i) == 83
        Z(i) = 2;
    elseif Z(i) == 52
        Z(i) = 3;
    elseif Z(i) == 36
        Z(i) = 4;
    elseif Z(i) == 28
        Z(i) = 5;
    elseif Z(i) == 23
        Z(i) = 6;
    elseif Z(i) == 125
        Z(i) = -1;
    else
       Z = Z(i);
    end
end
```

The largest value in the array is 140. However, when I run the code I receive this error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the line which certainly creates the error   Z = Z(i);  as you don't have any index on the left part

Comment: ^ ̶̶̶̶̶̶̶̶ certainly. If you want to keep the value unchanged if no condition satisfies, simply remove the else part. If the values that you're replacing are different than those with which you're replacing, you can get rid of the loop and if conditions with: `Z(Z== 140)=1;` `Z(Z== 83)=2` and so on...

Comment: @SardarUsama or [use `ismember`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869224/3978545) and you don't even need all the individual indexing conditions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line which certainly creates the error

```
Z = Z(i);
```

as you don't have any index on the left part.

Comment: Not sure this fully explains the issue... `Z=Z(i)` is a perfectly valid statement, it's not what the code is meant to do but it won't cause an error. The error comes when you then try and access `Z(i)` again (next loop) when `Z` isn't what is expected (it's now a scalar)

Comment: That's why if you remove that line, or you assign it correctly using an index, the error disappears, as the next loop interaction will be right

Comment: Yep agreed, I was just clarifying *why* that line causes an error :)

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is the `Z = Z(i)` line, you're assigning a single value to an array then trying to index that single value next loop. If you want to leave `Z(i)` unchanged, simply don't use the `else` condition.

This whole code could be a lot shorter (and less loopy) using some logical indexing and `ismember`:

```
% Row 1 values to be replaced in Z by row 2 values
replacements = [140, 83, 52, 36, 28, 23, 125; 
                  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  -1];
% Get the indices where Z is one of the values to be changed
[~, idx] = ismember(Z, replacements(1,:));
% Use indexing to replace all the values at once
Z(idx~=0) = replacements(2, idx(idx~=0));
```